# Problem with loading culture from XML using CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder on Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, culture

I have a web application that will use a few different cultures, one of which is es-US (Spanish United States). However, Windows XP do not have any support for the culture es-US. To work around the problem, I've found out that one is supposed to be able to use the CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder. So I looked into CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder and did the following:

On a Windows 7 machine I saved the culture es-US to an XML-file, as follows:

```
private static void SaveCultureToFile() {
            try {
                CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder = null;
                Console.WriteLine("Saving es-US to xml disc...\n");
                cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder("es-US", CultureAndRegionModifiers.Replacement);

                // Populate the new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder object with culture information.
                CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("es-US");
                cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(ci);

                cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Save("es-US.xml");

            }
```

Then I have a function that reads the xml, and registeres the culture into the system, as follows:

```
    private static void RegisterCultureFromDisk() {
        try {
            CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Loading es-US from xml...\n");
            cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder = CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.CreateFromLdml("es-US.xml");
            Console.WriteLine("Culture is registred to the system...\n");
            cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Register();
            Console.WriteLine("The following culture has been registred to the system: \n");

        }
```

So I run the program using the SaveCultureToFile method on a Windows 7 machine, thus saving the culture to an xml file. Then I copy the files to the Windows XP machine, and runs the same program but the RegisterCultureFromDisk() method. But the program fails in the CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.CreateFromLdml("es-US.xml") method saying that:

> "Culture name 'es-us' is not
>   supported"

Well, thats exactly why I'm trying to load the culture from the xml and registering it into the system.

Do any one know what I'm doing wrong, or how I can create the es-us culture at the Windows XP machine?

Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an ancient question, but I've recently run into this issue and managed to actually solve it.

Turns out the `CreateFromLdml` method can be tricked into loading a non-existing culture if you just create a temporary culture using the name of the one you want to import. Then you can unregister the temporary culture and register the one you just loaded instead.

I've made a simple command-line tool for exporting/importing cultures, which we've successfully used to add in some obscure missing cultures we needed when deploying new servers on Azure.

If you need it - the source code and a more in depth description of the solution is available [here](http://claus.nu/blog/importing-custom-cultures-on-an-azure-vm/).

Comment: Brilliant! Just what I needed to see. Still, it requires admin rights, would be nice if you could just set a volatile culture for a running process, but as far as I can tell, it needs to be installed on the system to be used.

Answer (score 0):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.aspx):

> Note that a custom culture can be registered on a computer only by a user who has administrative rights on that computer. Consequently, typical applications cannot create a custom culture.

I suspect it might be the cause of your problem... do you have admin rights on this machine ?

Comment: Yes I do, and I don't think this is what causes the problem. Found some useful information at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/books/CustomCultures.aspx. Seems that msLocale:textInfoName and ms:LocalesortName cannot refer to a culture that the machine doesn't have. Consequently, it seems impossible to have a full featured es-us culture registered at a windows xp machine. One can however create a custom culture that resembles the es-us culture as much as possible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it *can* refer to a culture the machine doesn't have, that's the whole point of creating a new culture. Once I created a "martian" culture, just to see if it was possible, and it worked fine